# Setting the background image of a window with uniformtofill

Tags: c#, background, set

I got this piece of code:

```
this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/myapp;component/Images/icon.png")));
```

works like a charm, but how do I include the stretch.uniformtofill setting?

Comment: can you confirm whether the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way using [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) syntax :

```
this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/myapp;component/Images/icon.png")))
                 {
                       Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill
                 };
```

Here is an interesting discussion about *object initializer* on programmers.stackexchange :

- [What is it called when you set properties on object initialization?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111344/what-is-it-called-when-you-set-properties-on-object-initialization)